# Firebase Realtime data key order checking

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to check if a key exists before or after a given reference key?

Here is my posts node:

```
-LFdM9Dfy7t-xiK-pO5h
-LFdPpn7wsRM3Y5TUPiN
-LFdQ0x1T6OF_FiCeIWk
-LFg41ZcFHgrI0VSY83v
-LFiTmj1OceTiAYqCflV
```

suppose my reference key is `'-LFdPpn7wsRM3Y5TUPiN'` I want to check key '-LFg41ZcFHgrI0VSY83v' exists before or after my reference key. Kinda got confused how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference keys are just strings, so you can compare them lexicographically like this:

```
firstKey.compareTo(secondKey)
```

this method returns a positive, negative or zero `int` based on the order, 
and because the first 48 bits of the keys are timestamps, the keys are ordered chronologically.

Comment: This is the best solution, Ahh I should go and study more about the firebase key structure. Thank you so much man :)

Answer (score 0):

Just loop though the reference keys and remember the index of `'-LFdPpn7wsRM3Y5TUPiN'` and `'-LFg41ZcFHgrI0VSY83v'`. Then check which number is bigger.

> EDIT:

Try the following:

```
if( yourReferenceKeyArray.indexOf( first key ) > yourReferenceKeyArray.indexOf( second key ) )
```

Comment: Umm, it'll be resource intensive if we have thousands of entries.

Comment: Edited answer. Look at the changes